# json array 1st one get value of 2nd one

Tags: json, angular

In Angular2, I have a JSON that returns Customer

Here is my Customer class:

```
export class Customer {
  customerNo: string;
  tckn: string;
  vkn: string;
  customerType: string;
  address: Address[];
  phone: Phone[];
}
```

and here is my Address class:

```
export class Address {
    addressType: string;
    tradeName: string;
    taxOfficeName: string;
    taxNo: string;
    addressName: string;
    addressString: string;
    building: string;
    floor: string;
    apartment: string;
    city: string;
    county: string;
    zipCode: string;
    addressDirection: string;
    department: string;
    indx:string;
}
```

And here is my json in my customer.service.ts;

```
getCustomerInfo(): any {
  return [{
    customerNo: '4767584',
    tckn: '968796',
    customerType: '1',
    address: [{
        addressName: '1.address',
        addressType: '1',
        city: '34',
        taxNo: '111'
      },
      {
        addressName: '2.address',
        addressType: '2',
        city: '6',
        apartment: 'test aprt'
      }
    ]
  }];
}
```

I append that json to my model in `customer.component.ts`

```
this.model = this._customerService.getCustomerInfo()[0] as Customer;
```

now I log `this._customerService.getCustomerInfo()[0] as Customer;`
and I see that json is ok.

[image]

now, log this.model the 1st address get values of 2nd address

[image]
do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What is type of model? Is the model bind to view, If so, May be due to same id or #id in view causes the issues. Better to post the .html code

Comment: yeap id issue, it solved. Thanks @Eel